# dplyr: categorical counts from a single column across multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, boxplot

So I have been trying to do a boxplot of "yes/no" counts for hours now.

My dataset looks like this

```
> stack
         Site Plot Treatment Meters Retrieved
2   Southern    18   Control  -5.00         y
3   Southern    18   Control   9.55         y
4   Southern    18   Control   4.70         y
5   Southern    27   Control  -5.00         y
6   Southern    27   Control  20.00         n
9   Southern    18   Control  -0.10         y
17  Southern    18   Control  20.00         y
23  Southern    31   Control 100.00         y
53  Southern    25        Mu   3.55         n
54  Southern    20        Mu   5.90         y
55  Southern    25        Mu  -0.10         y
56  Southern    29        Mu   9.55         y
58  Southern    25        Mu   4.70         y
60  Southern    20        Mu   2.90         y
61  Southern    24        Mu   5.90         n
62  Southern    24        Mu   3.55         y
63  Southern    20        Mu   3.55         y
65  Southern    24        Mu   0.55         y
66  Southern    29        Mu   8.90         y
68  Southern    25        Mu   8.90         y
69  Southern    29        Mu   0.55         y
70  Southern    24        Mu   1.70         y
72  Southern    29        Mu  -5.00         y
76  Southern    29        Mu   1.70         y
77  Southern    25        Mu   9.55         y
78  Southern    25        Mu  13.20         y
79  Southern    29        Mu   3.55         y
80  Southern    25        Mu  15.00         y
81  Southern    25        Mu  -5.00         n
84  Southern    24        Mu   8.90         y
85  Southern    20        Mu   6.55         y
86  Southern    29        Mu   2.90         y
92  Southern    24        Mu  -0.10         y
93  Southern    20        Mu 100.00         y
```

I want to get counts of both y(yes) and n(no) of the variable "Retrieved" while grouping for "Treatment" and "Meters".

So it should look something like this

```
 Treatment Meters        Yes   No
     Control  -5.00         2   0
     Control   9.55         1   2
     Control   4.70         1   1
     Control  20.00         0   2
         Mu   3.55         4   0
         Mu   5.90         0   1
         Mu  -0.10         2   2
         Mu   9.55         1   0
```

With this data I want to do a stacked boxplot with x=Meters, y= count and Treatment as grid or something.  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8qQq.png)

This is my code but it's not working

```
plot_data <- stack %>% 
  count(Retrieved, Treatment, Meters) %>% 
  group_by(Treatment, Meters) %>% 
  mutate(count= n)

plot_data

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Meters, y = count, fill = Treatment)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") + 
  geom_label(aes(label = count(count)), position = "fill", color = "white", vjust = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = count)
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `y= count` please specify I don't see count variable

Comment: in the code, where I state  "mutate(count=n)", am I not creating a new variable "count" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_bar` is for precisely this case, and you won't even need to use `group_by` or `count`. (From the docs: "`geom_bar` makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in each group".)

This should do what you're looking for:

```
ggplot(stack, aes(x = Meters, fill = Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack")
```

However, the bars will be very narrow because "Meters" is continuous and has a large range. You could address this by converting it into a factor. One way to do that would be to do this first:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Meters = as.factor(Meters))
```

[image: resulting plot]

If you want to get the counts in the format that you mentioned (in addition to creating the plot), you could do:

```
data %>%
  count(Treatment, Meters, Retrieved) %>%
  spread(Retrieved, n, fill = 0) %>% 
  rename(Yes = y, No = n)
```

`count` does `group_by` for you, so I didn't need to carry that over from your code. Then, `spread` creates the separate columns for `y` and `n`. Finally, I rename those columns to `Yes` and `No`.

Comment: Thank you! I had sort of found a way to do it but my "x=Meters" was still continuous and the graphs looked hideous.  Other than that, I was using the function "count" from the plyr package `count = count(d, c('Treatment','Meters','Retrieved'))
count`  but that was only giving a frequency table.